# Output location of images for django-imagekit

Tags: django, imagekit, django-imagekit

I'm trying to output a list of images that belong to each record in my app as below:

```
pri_photo = vehicle.images.all()[:1]
sec_photos = vehicle.images.all()[1:]
```

This first part is OK.  The part I'm having issues with is when I try

```
pri_photo.original_image.url
sec_photos.original_image.url
```

The above two lines of code give me a `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'original_image'`.  What could be the issue?

I also want the photos in `sec_photos` to be output as image1, image2,... upto the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[:1] just limits the number of records returned by the queryset, still it is a queryset result, not a single object.

to get a single object, you shoud use

```
[0]
```

or

```
[0:1].get()
```

but it's not safe, as it will raise an error if none objects match the query. to do it properly, use filter() and if result are present then get(), or

```
try:
    #get()
except modelname.DoesNotExist:
    # do shomething else
```

also, if you are looking for the latest object, maybe you can just use http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/get_latest/

Comment: I've managed to get pri_photo working as desired...all that remains is sec_photos